# Android browser compatibility and fragmentation

Tags: android, html

We have an iOS html5-based app. One of the questions that's coming up a lot is if and when we are going to port to Android.

Because it's mostly html5, a port should be relatively easy. However, the HTML looks different on my Moto G than it does on iOS, even though Chrome on my mac does render it correctly. Now, I have some experience with cross-browser html development from back in the netscape/ie6 days, so I can probably figure out what's going on.

What worries me more though, is the fragmentation. If I get it to render correctly on my Android device, how do I know it works correctly devices with an older version of the OS too? On iOS, we simply require iOS6, as most iPhone users upgrade their OS. On Android, this is a lot more difficult, as users don't tend to update (or the manufacturers don't even provide updates).

Do I need to get my hands on a ton of different devices to test on? Any easier ways to test this? I'm new to Android development, so any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common issue across Android Development. Device Fragmentation... our nemesis. What will make it even more difficult, as I have experienced, is that Android ditched the old WebView in favor of a Chromium based WebView in KitKat. So even the APIs are no longer the same from your Moto G to previous devices.

That said, there are a fair amount of resources available in helping assist with creating a Web App that will work with your site and the native device. Quite a few examples too.

I would begin here: https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/index.html which includes a subsection devoted entirely to the Chromium changes incorporated in KitKat (https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html)

Additionally, there is this Pixel Perfect information site as well: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/pixelperfect

Now you can set your minimum accepted and targeted API levels on Android, just as you would on iOS. For instance, if the minimum is 15 and it is targeted for 19, then you are specifying that your app will work for KitKat (4.4) devices, but support as old as Ice Cream Sandwich (4.0.3). There's really no reason to target an API lower than 15 anymore, unless something is very specific business reason to target a device that low. By specific, I mean more distinct than "we want to reach as many as possible."

Finally, there are emulators that you can create through the AVD (Android Virtual Device) manager that can replicate various OS levels and hardware configurations. A very popular emulator company called Genymotion (http://www.genymotion.com/) is also frequently used, however it is not free for commercial use.